# How can I repeat / scroll a tile which is part of an texture atlas?

Tags: glsl

I would like to scroll a tile which is part of a texture atlas like it can be done with a single quad and texture wrap mode set to repeat.

Can this be done? I hope it's clear what I would like to achieve.

Here is my shader code which I use to sample tiles from my texture atlas, but I can't figure out how to do the wrapping so that one tile repeats itself over time.

```
uniform float time
void main() {
  float texId = textureId/32.0;
  vec2 tileOffset = vec2(fract(texId)*32.0,floor(texId));
  vec2 offset = invTileCount * tileOffset;
  vec2 texCord = fract(vUv) * invAtlasSize + offset;
  vec4 texelColor = texture2D( uTex, texCord );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn´t this already do it? Assuming `vUv` to cover the whole 0-1 range for each tile. The `fract()` will make it wrap and then it is scaled and moved to actually fit your tile.

```
uniform float time
void main()
{
  float texId = textureId/32.0;
  vec2 tileOffset = vec2(fract(texId)*32.0,floor(texId));
  vec2 offset = invTileCount * tileOffset;
  vec2 texCord = fract(vUv+time) * invAtlasSize + offset;
  vec4 texelColor = texture2D( uTex, texCord );
}
```

The problematic part will be to handle the texture interpolation and mipmapping correctly if you need it. `textureGrad()` might be helpful, or you just implement it completely yourself using `texelFetch()`.

Comment: oh thanks yea you are right, I just have to add it to the vUv, it works.